# how to select specific records based on total sum value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following SQL table

```
ID Key Value
1  A   10
2  A   20
3  B   50
4  B   2
5  C   30
6  c   20
```

I need to select all records from this table where Value is a sum of 25. So, for Key A, record with ID 1 and 2 should come out. For Key B, record ID 3 and for Key C, the record ID should be 5.

I'm trying something like but this is giving an error, still trying.

```
select ID, Key, Value
from T
where Sum(value)> 25
Group by ID, Key
```

Any advice to get the desired set?

Edit: Added Server Name.

Comment: I don't see how your sample data produces your desired results.  Record ID 5 has a key value of "B", not "C", for instance.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking, because your sample data makes no sense, and also you never told us your actual database, which might determine which type of approach can be used.

Comment: Updated the data set, it got typo earlier

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . You might reconsider your close vote.  The question is reasonably clear.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want all rows with a given key value up to where the first running sum exceeds 25.  Use the cumulative sum function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(value) over (partition by key order by id) as running_value
      from t
     ) t
where running_value - value < 25;
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.. this makes sense

Comment: How do you know the OP's database supports analytic functions?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Analytic functions have been part of the SQL standard for decades and are available in all major databases (of course, that is part of my definition of "major", so it's a bit of a tautology ;).

Comment: Gordon, you got it right, as usual, but had the OP been using something like pre MySQL 8+ or maybe SQLite, your query would not have helped.  Just saying.